# How to align this checkbox

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table an done column is just checkboxes.

In the `<th>` I have a prompt "include?" and would now like to add some JS for a checkbox in that `<th>`, with maybe some "all/none" text.

Bad ascii art follows:

```
------------             ------------
| include? |             | include? |
|   []     |             |   [] all |
------------             ------------
|   []     |  or, maybe  |   []     |
------------             ------------
|   []     |             |   []     |
------------             ------------
```

in either case, what `style` should I use to centre that checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is with `text-align:center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/rhUjP/1/

**EDIT**

Just saw your other requirements, namely *I need the text to be left aligned, but the checkbox to be centered*

In that case, put the `input` in a `span`

```
span{display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:100px;}
```

Have the `width` match the `width` of the `th`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/rhUjP/3/

Comment: +1 thanks. I will look at it, but the width is dependant on the text and the font used, so can't really be predicted in PX

Comment: however, changing that 100px to 100% works, so you get awarded the answer. Thansk for helping, I think that I learned something

Answer (score 2):

```
.checkbox {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Or you can set:

```
th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And specify which `class` or `id` of `<th>` to include if you want the entire `<th>` to be centered, like: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/pJxgc/.

Comment: +1 Thanks, just one small problem ... I need the text to be left aligned, but the checkbox to be centered (don't ask why ;-)

Answer (score 2):

try this one [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjzHH/)

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><th><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello</th></tr>
            <tr><td>My Table Data!</td></tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

th {
    text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/h5ZTA/4/)?